# ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css")

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm doing this app on Rails, the page loads fine but in the console, this appears:

```
Started GET "/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css" for ::1 at 2020-08-17 09:09:51 -0500

Started GET "/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.min.js" for ::1 at 2020-08-17 09:09:51 -0500
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] 
"/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css"):
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] 
"/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.min.js"):
```

Inside my vendor folder, I have both folders, javascripts and stylesheets, and in both their respective bootsrtrap.min.
Even in the application.html.erb I have the following:

```html
  <link href="vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>

</head>
<body>

  <!-- Navigation -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark static-top">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Instagram Clone</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
              <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- Page Content -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
        <%= yield %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
  <!--<script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>-->
  <script src="vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

In both application files, js and CSS, I have put the "require bootsrtrap.min" and even with that error still appearing in my console.
What could it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Solution] So inside my Html (application.html.erb) I had two calls for both js and css files:

```html
<script src="assets/javascripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>       
<link href="assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 
  'reload' %>
```

As you can see above, in the case of the javascript, I have a call with script and other with <%=%>, having both was making the problem, so you just have to comment one, I comment the script one in the case of my java file and  in the case of CSS file.
Like this:

```html
  <!--<link href="assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
    <!--<script src="assets/javascripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>-->
```

And to me, that solves the problem, I tried really everything and this was the solution haha.

Answer (score 1):

RoR doesnt use the directory as the folder structure indicates. Because has a assets loader. You should import the css in application.css and the js in the application.js in rails 5 or less. And add the bundle file with its own helper:

### 1. Install bootstrap with yarn

```
yarn add bootstrap @popperjs/core jquery
```

or

```
npm i bootstrap @popperjs/core jquery
```

## Rails 5 or less

### 2. Import files in Assets Pipeline

#### app/assets/stylesheets/application.css:

```
//...
require bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min
//...
```

But if you want, I suggest to use the SCSS and only import the styles that you need.

#### app/assets/javascript/application.js:

```
//...
//= require jquery
//= require @popperjs/core
//= require bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min
//...
```

### 3. Import Assets in Layout

#### app/views/layout/application.html.erb:

```
<head>
...
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all' %>
</head>
<body>
...
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
</body>
```

## Rails 6 with webpack

### 2. Import Bootstrap in application.scss and application.js

#### app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss:

```
//...
import 'bootstrap'
//...
```

#### app/javascript/packs/application.js:

```
import 'jquery'
import 'popper.js'
import 'bootstrap'
import '../stylesheets/application'
```

### 3. Import bundle in Layout

```
<head>
...
  <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
</head>
```

After that you should be able to use bootstrap in all your app!

Comment: Did all that you suggested and didn't work. I even specified the path in HTML (vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.min) and put the requires already and still won't working.

Comment: If you dont want to install bootstrap with npm or yarn, add the files inside the js folder in app/assets/javascript and css file in app/assets/stylesheets. And just import it with the name. Or use the CDN

Comment: Thanks for your help!